# Adding the values of tuples together

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class WaitingList:
       
    def __init__(self):
           
        self.items = []   
     
    
    def stillWaiting(self, destination):
        newList = []
        index  = 0
        for i in range(0, len(self.items)):
            thisGroup = self.items[index]
            if thisGroup[1] == thisGroup[1]:
                duplicates = thisGroup[0] + thisGroup[0]
                newList = duplicates
            else:
                newList = i
    return newList
```

self.items stores a list of tuples e.g

```
self.items = [(3,"Rome"),(2,"Naples"),(1,"Pisa"), (1,"Florence"), (25,"Rome")]
```

I require my program to iterate through each tuple in any given list and if the destination i.e Rome is common in any of the tuples, add the numbers that appear beside the destinations in the tuples and store the results in a new list. So the expected result for above would be:

```
[28,"Rome"), (2,"Naples"),(1,"Pisa"), (1,"Florence")]
```

Thanks

Comment: `stillWating` get an argument named `destination`. What does it do with it?

Comment: Have you tried to write a routine to do what you need yet? What does it look like?

Comment: can `if thisGroup[1] == thisGroup[1]` be `False`?

Comment: It would allow the user to find out the number of people on a waiting list for a flight to the inputted destination.

Comment: balderman, yes I thought by using the 'for' statement it would iterate to the next tuple the list and compare the two values at index 1 which would be the destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

city_to_num = defaultdict(int)
for num, city in self.items:
    city_to_num[city] += num

output = [(num, city) for city, num in city_to_num.items()]
```

Comment: This doesn't touch the self.items from which the number and destination are coming from.

Comment: Was adding a generalizable solution. Just iterate over `self.items` instead of `items` as I had written previously.

Comment: This added the values but;

[(30, 'Rome'), (2, 'Naples'), (1, 'Pisa'), (1, 'Florence')]  waiting to fly to Rome
was returned 5 times when tested against a test file, I need;
30 waiting to fly to Rome, on one line
2 waiting to fly to Naples, on the next line

etc but the test file applies the "waiting to fly to"

Comment: This sounds out of scope to the original question.

Comment: Yes I know, I misinterpreted it, thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing a sort of frequency thing. So don't take this as an answer, but why not change how self.items works. Creating a tuple with a name and value seems a little naieve, why not create a dictionary and make use of something like setdefault or get so that you dont have duplicates in the dict in the first place, and if you must you can even convert the dict to a list of tuples using items()